# ng-click-outside: Click outside gets fired even for child elements

Tags: html, angular, typescript, onclick

I want to perform some task when i click out of the container.
For this I used **ng-click-outside** directive. It works fine otherwise except one case. Inside container i have one icon which toggles on click; but with this even **clickOutside** event gets fired.

I think issue is ng-click-outside checks if targeted element is present in the container and it doesn't finds it as I have ***toggeling elements*** in my container.

Is there any hack with this issue?

I have attached one example here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablesections-demo-nznnjo?file=src/app/app.component.html

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the directive has a property `[exclude]` that we can use. The problems are the "chevrons", so we need exlude the elements with class `.p-treetable-toggler`or `.pi-fw`. we can imagine that only write

```html
    <!--this NOT work-->
    <div class="tree" (clickOutside)="onClickedOutside($event)" 
       [exclude]="'.p-treetable-toggler,.pi-fw'">
       ....
    </div>
```

The reason is that the directive not check the elements with this class else, when change the `[exclude]`, store this HTMLElements, and each time we click, check this elements. So if we expand a node, this "chevron" is not store. Well we can create two variables and one function

```
  exclude:string=null
  tog:boolean=false;

  toogle()
  {
    this.tog=!this.tog;
    this.exclude=this.tog?".p-treetable-toggler,.pi-fw":
                          ".p-treetable-toggler,.pi-fw,.fake"
  }
```

So, we call this function each time we expand/collapsed a node and after we received the data from the service

```html
     <!--and (onNodeExpand) and (onNodeCollapse) to the p-treeTable-->
     <p-treeTable (onNodeExpand)="toogle()" (onNodeCollapse)="toogle()" ...>
```

And in ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.nodeService.getFilesystem().then(files => {
      this.files = files
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.toogle()
      })
    });
    ....
}
```

We use a setTimeout to say to Angular, "first paint the result, after remember call to this.toogle()"

You can see [your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetablesections-demo-hlfxvc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: if we only need know when We click if we click out or into an element we can use some more simple

If we has a "div"

```
<div #mydiv>
  ...
</div>
```

We can use `ViewChild`and `fromEvent` rxjs

```
  @ViewChild('mydiv',{static:true}) element;

  fromEvent(document,'mousedown').pipe(map(
    res=>this.element.nativeElement.contains(res.target)
  )).subscribe(res=>{
     console.log(res)
  })
```

Normally we want unsubscribe to the fromEvent, e.g. we only when click outside, make "something" and unsubscribe, so if use filter and take(1):

```
  fromEvent(document,'mousedown').pipe(
    filter(res=>!this.element.nativeElement.contains(res.target)),
    take(1)
  ).subscribe(res=>{
     console.log('You click outSide')
  })
```